# How to write mouse event for form button?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

How to write mouse enter event for minimize & maximize button of form in c#? When the mouse enters the minimize and maximize button, I do want to fire some event. How can I do that?

Please help.
Thank You.

Comment: Did you try anything? Read [FAQ] and [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this using the .NET Framework itself. You'd have to catch [WM_NCHITTEST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645618%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) window message. You'd then have to check what the default window function returns (`HTMAXBUTTON` for example) and then handle that.

Comment: WM_NCHITTEST seems to work fine with other hit points such as HTTOP, HTRIGHT, HTLEFT, ... but the HTCLOSE, HTMAXBUTTON, HTMINBUTTON When I move the mouse over those caption buttons, the HTTOP is hit instead. I'm using Windows 7 64bit, any idea?